# How to open UIPickerView with animation(bottom to top)

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How to open UIPickerView with animation(bottom to top)

Answer (score 0):

Make the initial position just below the screen.  When you want it just animate it to the final position.  Basically:

UIView beginAnimations
set the picker view frame to the new on screen location
UOIView commitAnimations